# TFOD Error: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to develop tensorflow object detection model using python on google colab.
While training I am getting error, I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2) and system just stucks their.